# How do I get Pokémon Go to detect my phone's orientation?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

When initiating a battle it starts off in AR mode, but then warns me saying my phone's orientation is not detected. I am then forced to turn off AR mode. Has anybody experienced this? If so, what are the solutions?

[image]

Per comments, I am unsure this is a permissions issue. I have everything turned on.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I would say this is a permission issue, but checking permissions for the app in Marshmallow doesn't seem to reveal anything obvious about orientation detection. Do you have auto-rotate turned off by chance?

Comment: Same happens on me. Auto rotate is disabled tho, will try enabling tomorrow.

Comment: I would test this right now.... but servers are down.

Comment: Auto rotate is enabled for me. I will poke around with the permissions

Comment: @MichaelFrank glad I'm not the only one ... :/

Comment: @Wondercricket - have you restarted your phone?

Comment: You also may need permission to use the camera. I had to allow camera use the first time I played

Comment: @Timelord64 Ahh, that could be it. Detection of rotation by using the camera.

Comment: Orientation might mean the direction the phone is facing -- namely, the compass. If your phone doesn't have one, it might cause AR mode to hang up.

Comment: Have you *ever* had this work? Gyro (aka auto rotate) is a fickle thing. While **it is a basic standard for an android phone**, it can also effectivley be disabled by light, unnoticeable damage. For example, light water damage can completely disable the gyro, while leaving the rest of the phone in otherwise perfect working condition. **Alternativley,** does the gyro work in general orientation? Does the GPS work correctly?

Comment: Only nitpicking, but the inclusion of such large screenshots seems less than ideal for visual format. It's not enough to warrant editing, IMO, but if you decide to [you can alter the size of an image](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8170/is-there-an-easy-way-to-resize-images-when-posting-them).

Comment: @Timelord64 I've always wondered how to do that. I will keep that in mind. I'm on mobile, so i wasn't able to judge size very well

Comment: What phone are you trying to use? I have a relatively uncommon phone (Sharp AQUOS Crystal) that I am experiencing the same issues with.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Based on comments and many articles I have read, this is a common issue among Android and iPhones. **The most common is your device may not be equipped with a Gyroscope.**

You can detect if your phone contains a Gyroscope via this app [Sensor Kinetics (Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innoventions.sensorkinetics&hl=en). I am not an Apple device owner, so I do not know any Apple version of the app. If your device is compatible with a Gyroscope, many say that a possible solution is to enable your auto rotation.

Unfortunately there is no way to install a Gyroscope into your device, this is only done during the manufacturing period. I have checked if an app-based Gyroscope will work, but Pokemon Go requires a built-in Gyroscope

[IDigitialTimes](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/pokemon-go-problems-fix-unable-authenticate-trainer-club-progress-gps-and-other-544335)

> **Problem #9: "Cannot detect your phone's orientation"error when switching to AR mode.**
>
> This is a problem a few of our readers recently reported. Searching the web it appears the issue could be one of two things:
>
> Android - your phone may not have a gyroscope. **If so, AR mode will not work**. A few phones reporting this issue are Sony Experia, HTC 626S and all Huawei smartphones.
>
> iOS - iPhone users with the iOS 10 beta 2 installed are also reporting problems with the phone detecting orientation for AR mode.

[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4ra29j/need_gyroscope/)

> Yes you need to have a gyroscope in your phone if you want to use the AR cam. Meaning if you want to see the Pokemon with a real life background, you need a gyroscope.
>
> The game itself will still work without a gyroscope, you'll be able to see the Pokemon with its animated background, just the AR (real life) camera won't work.

[Pokemon GO – Problems & Solutions](https://dnreviews.net/2016/07/08/pgo-prosol/)

> **Problem 10 – AR Mode/Camera Not Showing Pokemon**
>
> For many of you, when you toggle on AR Mode or the Camera, the Pokemon is no longer visible. You try to turn around to search for it but you still can’t find it. This totally removes the augmented reality experience that Pokemon GO has promised to deliver.
>
> So what’s the solution? For now, you can play by turning off the camera (AR) mode to see the Pokemon. This problem seems to affect older devices that lack Gyroscope more often but there are records of it affecting new devices as well. Some people reported new devices like the iPhone 6S for this problem and such devices might have a faulty Gyroscope.
>
> This problem may be fixed with an update from Niantic, so it is not entirely your device’s fault. Some who did experience this problem reported that by restarting the device the issue was solved. However, it does not work for everyone. Note that not everyone affected by it lacks a Gyroscope, this can be a compatibility issue and Niantic will have to address this in a future update to render the game compatible with your device.

---

**UPDATE**

If your phone is equipped with a gyroscope, then your issue may be something different (such as compatibility or older OS). For an issue such as this, Niantic may release further information and updates in the further.

[Pokemon GO common issues](http://fenixbazaar.com/pokemon-go-common-issues-and-how-to-fix-them/)

> **Pokemon GO camera not working**
>
> This is a similar issue to the “orientation” issue listed above, in that it’s generally related to your phone not supporting gyroscope technology. However, in some cases people are reporting that they still can’t access Pokemon GO‘s AR features even with gyroscope. This appears to be a not-so-common bug that is affecting older phones that support AR. For iPhone 6+ users, this could also be related to iOS 10 beta 2. It appears to be a bug and may be addressed in future updates.

If you are an Apple device owner running iOS Beta 1/2, reverting back to an older version ***may*** be a solution

> **Pokemon GO AR Mode not working**
>
> A number of players using iOS 10 beta 1/2 are reporting issues related to their phone not detecting orientation for AR mode. If possible, uninstall iOS 10 beta 2 and revert back to an older OS.

Comment: Why can't the app use the accelerometer in my phone? What's the difference between a gyro sensor and an accelerometer? :/

Comment: @BetaDecay [Accelerometer vs Gyroscope](http://www.livescience.com/40103-accelerometer-vs-gyroscope.html) is a good read

Comment: @Wondercricket That article is only painting half the picture. Your device's accelerometer and magnetometer can be used as a substitute for the gyro. (Notice how even devices without a gyro can rotate between landscape and portrait based on physical orientation.) In fact, the magnetometer is used to correct the gyro which accumulates drift over time. The magnetometer is superior in acquiring exact angles, but it is slower than the gyro. Bottom line, the developers **could** have made AR mode work without a gyro, but they were either too lazy or lack creativity.

Answer (score -1):

I think your phone doesnt have gyroscope sensor.
You can check it with app Sensor box in ps or as..
CMIIW